# Are 105 r5800 front derailleur and Claris rear derailleur compatible?

Tags: road-bike

I have full Clarice Road. I change the frame, but Claris front derailleur is impossible to fit the frame.
Claris front derailleur is a two-speed transmission.
105 r5800 front derailleur is also a two-speed transmission.
If I change the fron deraileur from Clarice to 105, Can I use a bicycle?
the sprocket and rear deraileur are eight-speed Claris.

Comment: Can you tell us what the mounts are, or why the original doesn't fit?

Comment: Cable pull ratio is completely different.

Comment: @MaplePanda Are you sure? The ratios for FDs are poorly documented. IIRC the ratio on Claris has changed in the current generation and migjt be compatible with other models.

Comment: @VladimirF https://bike-bikegremlin-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/?amp&amp_js_v=0.1&usqp=mq331AQKKAFQArABIIACAw%3D%3D#8

Comment: @MaplePanda That link suggests that all 8-10 are compatible but that is not correct. There is an  incompatibilty between older and the recent generations of lower level FDs as well. More specifically, according to Shimano, Claris 2400 and R2000 are NOT compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with 5800 front derailleur is that it's an 11-speed front derailleur.

Usually you can mismatch by a generation with front derailleurs, so that 8-speed and 9-speed can be interchanged. But in this case you would be mismatching by three generations.

I suspect the 11-speed front derailleur is made for far narrower chains so you'll have a terrible front derailleur chain rub. With friction bar-end or downtube shifter, it might be tolerable by trimming the front derailleur, but if you use indexed shifting for the front such as STI levers, you will have a very hard time trimming.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 5700 can?

Comment: 5700 is not a 9-speed front derailleur so you'll have problems even then. However 5700 is a 10-speed front derailleur. Less problems than with 11-speed.

Comment: oh my god... thank you.. I changed the frame to aircode fdj 2016. I dont have money.. So I want to use the Claris of my old bike. but frame front derailleur adapter is dont fit claris.. im so sad...

Comment: @Chun_KR Both Claris and 105 can be bought as braze-on and as clamp on. These are two different interfaces to the seat tube. If in doubt, do not hesitate to ask a question whether you can use Claris on your frame. Add photos.